# Bootstrap Jquery/Ajax Inline Edit when clicking Edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Can some one suggest me an inline edit were when I click on the edit button my label content should be replaced with an input text and I would be able to update it in my mysql db.

My code:

```
<label style="display:block;">mylabel</label>
<input type="text" style="display:none;">myinput</input>
<button>edit</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!!

Comment: does it have to be inline?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas yes it as to be inline its my requirement thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use contentEditable, if possible.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var btn = document.getElementById("editButton");

    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var editLabel = document.getElementById("editLabel");

        editLabel.contentEditable = true;
        editLabel.className = "editActive";
    });
});
```

```css
#editLabel{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#editButton{
    display: block;
}

.editActive{
    border: 1px inset #e3e3e3;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<label id="editLabel">Hello World</label>
<button id="editButton">Edit Label</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing it inline. As you can see the result will not be clean. This will work though.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label style="display:block;">mylabel</label>
<input type="text" style="display:none;" value="myInput">
<button onclick="$('label').text($('input').val())">edit</button>
```